# Find previous chunk to stage

Tags: tig

How do I navigate to the previous chunk to stage when viewing a single file in `tig status` mode?

What I'm looking for is the opposite to `stage-next` (mapped to `@` by default), but there is no `stage-previous` that I can find.

A previous question here at StackOverflow regarding a non-existing feature functioned somewhat as a feature request, which was later filled and referenced in an answer, which I'd love to see again if applicable.

Comment: Please use GitHub when you are quite sure this is actually a feature request. While I don't personally mind whether I get feedback from Tig users here or elsewhere, the 'format' of stackoverflow makes answering questions with 'yes, I just implemented that' somewhat questionable.

Comment: That's a valid point. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you point out there is no `stage-previous`. The preferred way to do this is to add a keybindings for prompt commands. Example:

```
bind stage 2 :?^@@
bind stage D :/^diff
```

Note that this is using a new feature that will be part of the upcoming release of version 2.0.